# Affecting ScaleType or applying a Matrix to AnimationDrawable

Tags: android, animation, matrix, bitmap, drawable

I have no trouble getting an AnimationDrawable to work, but it always streches to the full size of the ImageView (if I have layout_height, width to fill_parent).  Interestingly, when I set the layout_height, width to anything else (wrap_content, specific pixel, etc.), the animation doesn't show at all.  Doesn't matter if I use an Image setImage or setBackgroundImage, same results.

What would be ideal is if I could apply an existing Matrix to the entire list of AnimationDrawables.

Here is the code...
`

```
            wxChartAnimation = new AnimationDrawable(); 
            int numCharts = subChart.getChartCount();
            for (int i=0; i < numCharts; i++) {
                WeatherChart.BaseChart baseChart = subChart.getBaseChart(i);
                File file = new File(baseChart.localPath);
                if (file != null && file.exists()) {
                    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(baseChart.localPath);
                    if (d != null) {
                        if (wxChartAnimation != null) {
                            wxChartAnimation.addFrame(d,250);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            wxChartAnimation.setOneShot(false);
            wxChartImage.setImageDrawable(wxChartAnimation);
            wxChartAnimation.start();`
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also had this problem.  For what its worth, I came across a hack workaround for my purposes.  It seems that when you create an AnimationDrawable programmatically using "new AnimationDrawable()", it will not respect the scaleType of the ImageView.  However, if you use a .anim xml resource with a list of frames inside that reference resource drawables, it will take the size of the first image and scale the animation appropriately according to your ImageView's scaleType.  Since I am trying to load images from the assets folder into my AnimationDrawable, I needed to do it from code.  I ended up doing the following:

In res/anim/empty.xml (where empty_slide is a transparent image of the size I will be using for the rest of the animation):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="true">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/empty_slide" android:duration="0" />
</animation-list>
```

Then in my java file:

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.anim.empty);
AnimationDrawable animationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable)imageView.getDrawable();
animationDrawable.addFrame(Drawable.createFromStream(context.getAssets().open(drawablePath), null),animationDuration);
// Add the rest of the frames
...
animationDrawable.start();
```

I'd love to hear if you found a better way...

Answer (score 0):

I'm find some another way...

Problem is - "new AnimationDrawable()" don't set CurrentDrawable => not set height and width of AnimationDrawable.

I solved the problem this way:

```
protected void playFrameAnimationWithCurrentFrame(final ImageView ImView,final AnimationDrawable AnimDrawable){
    ImView.post(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            AnimDrawable.start();
        }});//We start the animation so that we have the current frame on which the matrix for mapping is based

    Thread t = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(AnimDrawable.getCurrent()==null){//wait for the current frame to appear                    
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            ImView.post(new Runnable(){//stop the current animation to assign animation to view and restart 
                public void run(){
                    AnimDrawable.stop();
                }});
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ImView.setImageDrawable(AnimDrawable);}
            });

            ImView.post(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    AnimDrawable.start();}});
            interrupt();
        }};
    t.start();
}
```

After that, the animation will be played with the matrix, which we previously installed on ImageView.

This method does not need .xml resource files.